# Get an error with the null attribut in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this javascript code here:

```
let elements = [];
window.onload = function(){
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements")) == null){
        elements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements"));
        console.log(elements)
        display();
    }
};

function addElement() {
    if(document.querySelector(".addTxt").value.trim() != ""){
        elements.push(document.querySelector(".addTxt").value.trim());
        if(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements") == null){
            localStorage.setItem("todo-elements", JSON.stringify(elements));
        }
        else{
            localStorage.setItem("todo-elements", JSON.stringify(elements));
        }
        display();
    }
}
```

The error I get come at line 13 is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null**
But I don't found the problem and how to solve this. What do I have to change? The full code with html/css is here: https://codepen.io/Tiger567/pen/KKWRyda

Comment: Could you please explain the logic of `if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements")) == null){ elements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements"));`…`}`? If the local storage entry, parsed as JSON, turns out to be `null`, set `elements` to that which is `null`. So `elements` is `null` right away. Read the error: _“Cannot read property '`push`' of `null`”_. What is being read? The property `push`. Property of what? Of `null`. Where does this happen? At `elements.push`. So `elements` is `null`. Did you mean to check `localStorage.getItem("todo-elements") !== null`, instead?

Comment: yes I would  check the last instead

Comment: My friend told me that I have to check if it‘s null, but if I don‘t need this. I can delete it

Comment: You should check if `getItem` returns `null` _in order to use a fallback value_. Currently, you’re not using the value from `getItem` and instead _replace the fallback value by `null`_. Your check is exactly backwards. This is a logic problem. What _should_ happen if `getItem` returns `null`? What _should_ happen if `getItem` returns _something other_ than `null`? Think about that and update your `if` statement accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

When you're trying to get the item from localstorage for the first time, it'll be null. Which is the reason for your issues.

Try replacing your onload code snippet with following snippet:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements")) == null){
        elements = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todo-elements"));
        if(!elements) 
            elements = [];
        console.log(elements)
        display();
    }
};
```

Comment: but now if I refresh the page, the  todos are deleted!